# A Machine learning model that has a undefined input size but a fixed output?

Tags: machine-learning, python, tensorflow

I don't know too much about ML but I can seem to figure out how to train something like this. If you guys could list some possible ways to do this, thank you.

Comment: This is not a valid question just someone who doesn't want to read.

Comment: what does undefined input size means, is it the number of the rows or the number of columns or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options to "collapse" a variable-length input into a single value:

- Recurrent neural networks (RNN), either vanilla RNNs or more powerful variants like long-short term memories (LSTM) or gated recurrent units (GRU). With these, you "accumulate" the information of each time step in the input and at the end, you get your fixed-size output.
- Pooling, either average pooling or max pooling. You just compute the average/maximum of the representation across the time dimension.
- Padding. You just assume a maximum length for the data and create a neural network that receives a piece of data of such a length. For any input data that is shorter, you just add some "padding" elements at the end until they have the maximum size.

Comment: I thought about using RNNs but this would have to run hundreds to thousands of times forcing me to use a LSTM or GRU which would make the training time extremely long but pooling shouldn't take too long and be able to handle it

Answer (score 0):

For Deep Learning (neural networks), there techniques like Adaptive Average Pooling and Adaptive Max Pooling which outputs a fixed number of values irrespective of the size of the input to these layers.